# quarkus dev build failes with customized outputDirectory in pom.xml of dependend module

Tags: java, maven, quarkus

I started with a quarkus multi maven-module project and encountered the following problem when starting quarkus in the dev mode (mvn quarkus:dev) to support hot reload for depended modules' classes:
A module "my-app" configures its' build output path via the
`<project><build><outputDirectory>build</outputDirectory>` in the pom.xml. The module is build successfully, and the output exists in path my-app/build instead of the default target/classes. 
Then the build of another module "momsServerQuarkus", which depends on the "my-app", and which uses quarkus-maven-plugin, fails with error:
`[ERROR] Failed to execute goal io.quarkus:quarkus-maven-plugin:2.11.0.Final:dev (default-cli) on project momsServerQuarkus: Failed to run: Hot reloadable dependency de.kwsoft.moms:my-app:6.14.0-SNAPSHOT has not been compiled yet (the classes directory S:\trunk\moms\my-app\target\build does not exist)`
As visible in the error message, the `<outputDirectory>build</outputDirectory>`is read correctly from the my-apps' pom.xml, but is appended to the default output path "target" instead of the projects root folder. I played also variables, e.g. `<outputDirectory>${basedir}/build</outputDirectory>`, but the variable is not resolved by the quarkus-maven-plugin.
Does anyone know how this could be solved, or whether this could be a bug?
Thank you in advance.